# Валидация w3 css3

Tags: html, css, валидация

Кто может помочь растолковать ошибки валидатора?

Выводит **Character x is not allowed in prolog.**

[image: validator.w3.org]

Comment: тут до валидатора, как до Луны пешком.

Comment: @ а что это означает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть невидимый символ — Byte Order Mark — в файле. Сохраните вашу страницу в формате UTF без BOM (в Sublime Editor, например, есть такая опция).

Comment: В Notepad++ еще есть такая опция